# Conversão de LONG RAW para BLOB no Oracle

Tags: oracle

Tentei utilizar `TO_LOB` para converter o valor `LONG RAW` no `insert` porém retorna:

> ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes tips

O destino é uma coluna `BLOB` de uma tabela já em utilização do sistema, não podendo ser alterado o seu tipo com `ALTER MODIFY`, a solução foi criar uma tabela intermediária NOVA com a coluna do tipo `BLOB` para servir de conversão e somente após realizar o `INSERT` na Tabela Final com os tipos das colunas iguais(`BLOB`).

Comment: Retorna erro? você também pode tentar converter a coluna na própria tabela (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_long_lob.htm#i1006316)

Comment: ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes tips, não consigo alterar a tabela original é uma migração, e não posso alterar o destino pois já possui outros dados.

Comment: Você pode enviar a sentença?

Comment: Resolvi criando uma tabela intermediária temporária com a coluna do tipo BLOB e posteriormente importar na tabela Destino.

Comment: @AndreyHideki, pode adicionar uma resposta de como ficou a tabela? Assim caso alguem passe pelo problema,conseguira resolver tbm. vlw